# How do you update cached EF from database after SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Here's the scenareo - Different users are making changes by selecting a value from a drop down list on a web page. The drop down is contained either in a DataView or via building a table. If User A makes a change to line 1, it updates the database and shows their change after rebinding. Subsequently, User B is on the same page when user A makes their change and makes a change to line 2. The database is updated and the gridview is rebound (or table is rebuilt). However User B does not see the change made by User A. I'm assuming this is due to EF caching. If the user refreshes the page (or is redirected back to it), they can see the latest data in the database.

**How do I get the latest data from the database without refreshing the page?**

The method that binds is called in PageLoad everytime including postback:

```
    private void PopulateFormForDealer(DateTime BeginDate, DateTime EndDate, int DealerID, bool UnVerifiedOnly)
    {
        try
        {                
        using (var DB = new NIMSModel.NIMSEntities())
        {

    var scheduledOrders = from r in DB.Reservations
              join o in DB.Orders on r.ResID equals o.ReservationID
              where r.ResDate <= EndDate && r.ResDate >= BeginDate && r.Claimed == "Y"
              && r.DealerID == DealerID //&& r.Verified == VerifiedOnly
              orderby r.ResDate, r.ResID
              select new { r.ResID, o.ID, o.VantiveOrderID, o.CustomerFirstName, o.CustomerCity, o.CustomerState, o.CustomerZipCode, o.OrderType.Type, r.ResDate, r.TimeOfDay, r.Source, DealerInstallerID = r.DealerInstallerID == null ? 0 : r.DealerInstallerID, r.Verified, r.Notes };


    GridView1.DataSource = scheduledOrders.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
LogError(ex);
}
```

}

Here is the event handler for the drop down list:

```
    protected void ddInstaller_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
string foo = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
Guid theg = new Guid(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.Split('_')[1].ToString());
int? installerid = int.Parse(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.Split('_')[0].ToString());
string installername = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem.Text;

if (installerid == 0)
{
    installerid = null;
}

int testvalidguidlen = theg.ToString().Replace("0", "").Length;
if (testvalidguidlen > 10)
{
    string note;
    using (var DB = new NIMSModel.NIMSEntities())
    {
    var reservatoins = DB.Reservations.Where(r => r.ResID == theg).FirstOrDefault();

    if (reservatoins.DealerInstallerID != installerid)
    {
        var orders = DB.Orders.Where(o => o.ReservationID == theg).FirstOrDefault();

        reservatoins.DealerInstallerID = installerid;
        orders.InstallerID = installerid;

        if (reservatoins.Notes == null || reservatoins.Notes.Length >= 1800)
        {
        note = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss") + "] TechChange by: " + PTNAccount.UserName + "(" + PTNAccount.LoginID + "); NewTech: " + installername + ";";
        }
        else
        {
        note = reservatoins.Notes + "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss") + "] TechChange by: " + PTNAccount.UserName + "(" + PTNAccount.LoginID + "); NewTech: " + installername + ";";
        }
        reservatoins.Notes = note;

        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
    }
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
LogError(ex);
}
```

}

Here us the method that builds the drop down list:

```
    private DropDownList PopulateInstallerDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, String resID)
    {

try
{
using (var DB = new NIMSModel.NIMSEntities())
{
    var DealerInstallers = from di in DB.DealerInstallers
               where di.Active == 1 && di.IsDeleted == "N" && di.DealerID == DealerID
               orderby di.Name
               select new { di.ID, di.Name };
    var DealerInstallersArray = DealerInstallers.ToArray();
    ListItem li = new ListItem("","0_" + resID);
    ddl.Items.Add(li);

    foreach (var installer in DealerInstallersArray)
    {
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(installer.Name.ToString(), (installer.ID.ToString() + (string)"_" + resID.ToString())));
    }
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
string foo = ex.Message;
}
return ddl;
```

}

Here is the RowDataBound event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
string reservationID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ResID").ToString();
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddInstaller");
PopulateInstallerDropDownList(ddl, reservationID);
string dealerInstallerId = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DealerInstallerID").ToString();

if (dealerInstallerId != "0")
{
    dealerInstallerId = dealerInstallerId + "_" + reservationID;
}

if (dealerInstallerId.Length > 1)
{
    ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue(dealerInstallerId));
}
}
}
```

I've done multiple searches for a solution over the past two days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with EF caching at all, by default there is no data caching unless you are using a custom caching provider.

Comment: How often does the data change and how important is it that the users have the most current information right now?  The easiest solution is an update panel on a timer.  But will that be enough for you?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're invoking the binding method on a postback? As ToList() will always invoke the query and as BrokenGlass mentioned there is no default data caching.

Comment: @hyp unless I read it wrong his desire is that when I click the submit button he wants to update your page too.

Comment: I understood it that when I click submit the changes made by someone else don't appear.... ? confusing

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework 3.5 saves changes in an Unbelievable manner, but it fixed in EF 4.0
I guess that your using EF 3.5

Hover you need to know what happen to your data and how EF save data. you can read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) about this problem.

for now you can call refresh method to update data when you SaveChanges.

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders);
```

EF 4.0 > EF 3.5

Answer (score 0):

User B does not see changes made by User A because User B's changes overwrote the change made by User A.

What you want to do is implement a concurrency check in your system. So when User A and User B fetch the same instance of an object in the database, the first person to make a change and submit to the database will succeed. The changes made by the second person will fail with a concurrency exception - because your backend system will detect that User B made changes to a 'stale' entity that has been modified by a previous change.

Since you are using EF, you are in luck because it has a nice system that manages concurrency for you. Choose a property in your entity to use for concurrency checks - typically it is the "Last Modified Date" of an object.

Open the EDMX file, click on your desired property that you wish to use for concurrency checks (e.g. LastDateModified), and set ConcurrencyMode=Fixed.